# Responsive HTML Email Template Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, alignment

I am using a template I downloaded to create a newsletter for my company. The layout works great and looks great, however, we are required to have an ad. When the display of the email responds to a smaller browser and/or mobile view the ad is aligning atop the first section of content vs. below it. My goal is for the ad to display to the right when viewed on desktop but move below the content when viewed on mobile.

Here is the css I am using:

```
body {
width:100%!important;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

  .ExternalClass {
width: 100%;
  }

  span{
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#000;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

table[class="content_wrap"] {
  width: 94%!important;
}

table[class="full_width"] {
  width: 100%!important;
}

    table[class="hide"], img[class="hide"], td[class="hide"] {
  display: none !important;
}

td[class="text-center"] {
  text-align: left!important;
}


a[class="button"] {
  border-radius:2px;
  -moz-border-radius:2px;
  -webkitborder-radius:2px;
  background-color:#0F253F;
  color:#fff!important;
  padding: 5px;
  display:block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#logo {max-width:320px;max-height:24px;margin-left:5px;}
#banner {max-width:100%;}
.img {display:none;}
```

And here is the section of html I am struggling with:

```
<!--Content 1-->
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="background:#fff;">
            <tr>
              <td width="4"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#fff" width="100%" valign="top">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#fff">
                  <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#fff" style="background:#fff;">
                   <!--AD TABLE-->   
                   <table width="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" class="full_width">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%" class="text-center">
                            <!--image-->
                            <img style="display: block;" src="http://www.creditunions.com/assets/1/7/advertisement1.gif" border="0" alt="advertisement" width="300" height="20" /> <a href="http://pages.callahan.com/TCU_InvestmentTrends.html"><img style="display: block;" title="Trust Mutual Funds" src="http://www.creditunions.com/assets/1/7/Trust-Quarterly-anaimated--2.gif" alt="Trust Mutual Funds" width="300" height="250" id="ad" /></a><br/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table><!--END AD TABLE-->
                      <!--SPACER TABLE-->
                      <table width="20" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" class="hide">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%">&nbsp;

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table> 
                      <!--END SPACER TABLE-->
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="full_width">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%" class="text-center" style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:20px;color:#555;"><span style="color:#70090A;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;line-height:22px;">READ & WATCH</span><br />
                            <a href="http://www.creditunions.com/articles/prepare-for-the-unexpected/" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:27px;color:#2b6b87;margin:0;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;line-height: 22px;">Prepare For The Unexpected</a>
                            <br /><span style="font-size:14px;color: #a4a4a4;">By Name/span><br /><br />
                            <span>Not long before the financial crisis hit in 2008, Financial Partners Credit Union reduced its subprime consumer loan ratio from 28% to 8%, a decision that  seemed nothing short of prophetic when the economy sailed off a cliff later that year.  But at the time, there was nothing prescient about the decision.  It was simply a natural consequence of the strategic plan the credit union had conceived three years earlier.<br /><br /> In today&rsquo;s Q&amp;A, CEO Nader Moghaddam breaks down how Financial Partners&rsquo; strategic planning process works and how the credit union prepares for the unknown  using scenario planning.</span>
                            <br /><br />
                            <a href="http://www.creditunions.com/articles/prepare-for-the-unexpected/" class="button" style="color: #2b6b87;font-family: Calibri, 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:22px;">Read more &raquo;</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td width="4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="4">
              <td width="4">
                <table width="4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#d9dfe2"></td>
                    <td width="3" colspan="3" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="2" colspan="2" bgcolor="#d9dfe2"></td> 
                    <td width="2" colspan="2" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="3" colspan="3" bgcolor="#d9dfe2"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td width="100%" bgcolor="#ECF0F5"></td>
              <td width="4">
                <table width="4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="3" colspan="3" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#d9dfe2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="2" colspan="2" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="2" colspan="2" bgcolor="#d9dfe2"></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="1">
                    <td width="1" bgcolor="#acb4b8"></td>
                    <td width="3" colspan="3" bgcolor="#d9dfe2"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--end Content 1-->
```

Again, my goal is to have the ad appear below the "read more" blue button when viewed on moble.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that your ad table should be after your content table in the code, so it will pop below when resized.

Use [this responsive template from EOA](http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/Responsive_Template1.html) as a good example to build from.

Comment: I tried to move the table below the content table, however, when viewing it on the desktop the ad now appears below and to the right of the content vs. directly to the right.

Comment: Hard to comment on that without seeing the code - try mimicking the code from the part of the template that has similar functionality. If you get close, but still can't get it to work try posting a jsfiddle or something so we can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

99% of email clients remove all stylesheets (and any inline styles that may interfere with the mail client UI), therefore responsive email designs cannot be built using this technique.

Comment: Thanks for that info. The client we use to deliver our emails actually allows us to include css--and I have tested it as needed and we are happy with the layout even in clients it doesn't fully work on. So I am still trying to see if I can get this to work.

Comment: You have your own custom email client?

Comment: we use a company called DMI.

Comment: Don't confuse DELIVERY with CLIENTS. Just because you can send it, doesn't mean anyone will receive it.

Comment: As John says above - allow the natural width/flow to dictate - not CSS.